# Is the libboost-all-dev package debian package thread aware?

Tags: boost, thread-safety, debian, mt

I have installed the `libboost-all-dev` package (debian), and cannot find the libraries I need inside my `/usr/lib/` directory. (libboost_system-mt.a)

Are the library files that aren't suffixed with `-mt` thread aware? (As none of them are suffixed)

Comment: Suffixes can be present or absent, depending on flags used in `b2` command-line (eg., `--layout`). One way to be sure what libs you use is to build boost yourself - it's really simple.

Comment: @IgorR. I know it's simple, I've built boost before, but I'm just in love with automatically updating / removing all files using a package manager.